# the reason for p-p plot nonlinar

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I use library(fitdistrplus) package to fit the data as following:

```
set.seed(100)
x1<-rlnorm(500,1,3)
f.x1<-fitdist(x1,distr = "lnorm",method = "mme")
plot(f.x1)
```

following is the plot result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV2x5.png)

my question is :  the x1 data in fact is generated with rlnorm, but after fitting, the pp plot is not so perfect, how to explain this?

thanks.
Guangming

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect it is because moment matching isn't a great way of estimating the parameters. I repeated your example using moment matching:

```
set.seed(100)
x = rlnorm(500, 1, 3)

library(fitdistrplus)
f.x<-fitdist(x,distr = "lnorm",method = "mme")
```

The parameter estimates were:

```
> f.x
Fitting of the distribution ' lnorm ' by matching moments 
Parameters:
        estimate
meanlog 3.012574
sdlog   2.199019
```

If I do the fitting using maximum likelihood:

```
ll = function(meanlog, sdlog){
  sum(dlnorm(x, meanlog, sdlog, log = TRUE))
}

objFun = function(params){
  -ll(params[1], params[2])
}

optim(c(0, 1), objFun)
```

Then I get parameter estimates of

```
> optim(c(0, 1), objFun)
$par
[1] 0.8861808 3.0118166
```

which are much closer to the values you were sampling from I think you'd agree. So the quantiles (and percentage points) are going to be a lot closer to the empirical values.